# ¿What programming language is this?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm studying Software Testing at my university and in the book I found this example:

[image]

I have no idea what programming language is it. ¿Can you help me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome on SO. First of all, I suggest you to have a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), for your question is definitely out of policies. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [PDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Design_Language). It is related to pseudocode, but unlike pseudocode, it is written in plain language. I determined this by using Google to find that example and then read the context & sentences surrounding it..

This image was found on [Page 397](https://books.google.com/books?id=bL7QZHtWvaUC&pg=PA397&lpg=PA397#v=onepage&q&f=false) of "Software Engineering: A Practitioner's Approach" By Roger S. Pressman.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive answer.